# how to create a link to a module in yii ?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Hello and thanks for reading.

I was wondering how i can link to a file from my main site to a module

eg ; 
if i am in `protected/views` on a file and i want to link to `protected/modules/user/profile` where i call an action.

Now i get an error that states that action user does not exists.

How can i create a link to a module following the following yii sintax ;

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Link Text',array('link to module',
                                 'param1'=>'value1')); ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php echo CHtml::link(Yii::app()->createurl('Module/Controller/Action'),array(
'param1'=>'value1')); ?>
```

Comment: in my case it should have a an extra(slash) / Yii::app()->createurl('/Module/Controller/Action')

Answer (score 1):

this may help with combining CHtml::link with a link to a module and it's controller/action combination:

```
echo CHtml::link("click here", 
    Yii::app()->createurl('/module/controller/action', array(
        'id' => $model->id // Params
    ))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to figure it out i tried to put this and it works ''`/user/profile`'' 
anybody has other ideas let me know